# Multiple useState in if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a small tennis match simulator.

And so far everytime a player reach actualScore: 4 I would like to update my player useState and add +1 to their setWon, however it never update it and I don't get why. The block of code:

```
    if (playerOneData.actualScore >= 4) {
      setPlayerOneData({ ...playerOneData, setWon: playerOneData.setWon + 1 })
      setPlayerOneData({ ...playerOneData, actualScore: 0 })
      setPlayerTwoData({ ...playerTwoData, actualScore: 0 })

    }
```

All the code:

```
function App() {

  const [playerOneData, setPlayerOneData] = useState({
    name: "blabla",
    level: 2,
    setWon: 0,
    actualScore: 0,
  })

  const [playerTwoData, setPlayerTwoData] = useState({
    name: "blabla",
    level: 4,
    setWon: 0,
    actualScore: 0,
  })

  const generateRandomBall = () => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    console.log(random);
    if (playerOneData.actualScore >= 4) {
      setPlayerOneData({ ...playerOneData, setWon: playerOneData.setWon + 1 })
      setPlayerOneData({ ...playerOneData, actualScore: 0 })
      setPlayerTwoData({ ...playerTwoData, actualScore: 0 })

    }
    else if (playerTwoData.actualScore >= 4) {
      setPlayerTwoData({ ...playerTwoData, setWon: playerTwoData.setWon + 1 })
      setPlayerTwoData({ ...playerTwoData, actualScore: 0 })
      setPlayerOneData({ ...playerOneData, actualScore: 0 })

    }
    else if (random > 50) {
      setPlayerOneData({ ...playerOneData, actualScore: playerOneData.actualScore + 1 })

    }
    else if (random <= 50) {
      setPlayerTwoData({ ...playerTwoData, actualScore: playerTwoData.actualScore + 1 })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Where do you display the values? How do you know values don't change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. useState is an asynchronus operation. So when you are trying to call multiple setState at the same time the execution is messed up.
2. also you will need to set the data based on the previous data.

Here is how the code should be modified

```js
setPlayerTwoData(prevData => {
  return {
    ...prevData,
    actualScore: 0,
    setWon: prevData.setWon + 1
})
```

and the updates should work correctly

Comment: *"...when you are trying to call multiple setState at the same time the execution is messed up."* More specifically, because they're using the non-callback form, when calling `setPlayerTwoData` twice in a row, the second update completely overwrites the first.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the more precise explanation.